# Why does「远」have difficulty displaying?

Tags: characters

I have noticed that「远」often has difficulty displaying in Chinese subtitles. It is usually replaced with □ - a white box used for a missing or unsupported Unicode character. If the character was part of CJKV extension blocks I could understand why it might sometimes have display issues. But for a simple, well established character like「远」it doesn't really make any sense. I have seen the same issues in .srt files and .ass files.

My guess is that it might have something to do with regular script (楷体) as I have seen similar issues with「红」that seem to stem from problems with Kai.

It's surprising to see problems with such basic characters.

Ideas?

Comment: Not sure what your issue is, but some fonts designed for Traditional Chinese have missing glyphs for Simplified Chinese characters. And similarly for fonts designed for Japanese or Korean. For example, Yu Gothic (for Japanese) and Malgun Gothic (for Korean) have no glyphs for 远 (U+8FDC) or 红 (U+7EA2)

Comment: @qrsngky That might just be the answer. I'm not 100% sure either - it may be a VLC issue if what you're saying is correct. Perhaps something to do with fallback fonts.

Comment: Maybe you can experiment with the settings https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Adjust_subtitle_font_settings/